# Add text to a preexisting notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have an activity that generates a notification that triggers after 30minutes.
My notification works fine.  The notification can be dismissed by the user but will persist until dismissed (this is a deliberate action).

If I run the activity again, I wish for the new information passed from the activity to be appended to the existing notification. 
I am struggling to write a conditional method that updates the notification, appending text rather than replacing the content text that is already in it.

This is all held in a receiver class that is called by pending intent:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent notifyIntent) {
    //attempt at using existing number held in the notification
    if (notifyNumber != null){
        oldNoticationNumber = " + " + notifyNumber;
    } else {
        oldNotificationNumber = "";
    }


    //Import Variables

    numberFromActivity = notifyIntent.getStringExtra(ImplementingClass.numberFromActivity);
    if ("".equals(numberFromActivity)){
        numberFromActivity = "..(NOT SUPPLIED)..";
    }
    notifyNumber = numberFromActivity + oldNotificationNumber;


    //Notification
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    int notifyID = 1;
    Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Check blah blah blah for...")
                .setContentText("A number: " + notifyNumber)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setSound(notificationSound)
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 500, 200, 500, 200, 500,200 });

    // Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is
    // updated.
    mNotificationManager.notify(
            notifyID,
            mNotifyBuilder.build());
}
```

as you can see, what I thought would work is that if the notification is still alive (i.e. has not been dismissed) it would hold the variable

```
Private String notifyNumber
```

however all it does is replace the previous content text with a new notifyNumber.

If however the notification has been dismissed already then I want it only to display the new notifyNumber.

I am trying to avoid creating multiple Pending Intents.

Comment: At the moment, all I have done is set the pending intent to create a new notification if the variable changes and this then stacks up in the notification drawer. I would still like a solution to the above though.